# Is there one extension or code to limit Magento 2 REST API per store?

Tags: php, rest, magento2, magento2.1

i have a multi-store application on magento 2 integrating with a desktop software by REST. But i see the magento 2 does not limit users per store. Is there one extension or code to limit Magento 2 REST API per store?

All responses will be appreciate.